# Behaviour of Ansible hosts: setting on Vagrant or Docker

Tags: docker, vagrant, ansible

I provision a Vagrant box with Ansible, and my ansible/site.yml contains the following `hosts` entry:

```
---
- hosts: all
```

I decided to setup a CI to test the Ansible code under ansible/. But with Docker, Ansible complains:

```
PLAY [all] ***************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

Then I changed the hosts entry to `localhost`, and now it works in Docker!  But now it refuses to run under Vagrant!

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

I am not using Vagrant and Docker together! Vagrant is used in my machine and Docker in the CI, but both run the same Ansible playbook!

**TL;DR:** Vagrant only works with `hosts: all`, and Docker only works with `hosts: localhost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you start `ansible-playbook` with an empty inventory in your CI environment.
Add `-i 'local,' -c local` parameters to define inventory with one host `local` and connection mode set to `local`.
Your command line should look like:

```
ansible-playbook -i 'local,' -c local playbook.yml
```

In this case `hosts: all` will work fine.